# Plot : e^x*sin(x^2+y^2)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot the equation: e^x*sin(x^2+y^2), but the result in LaTeX is clearly different with the actual graph drawn with Geogebra. What is the reason?

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \begin{axis}[
        title={$e^{x}\sin(x^{2}+y^{2})$}, 
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
        small,
    ]
    \addplot3[
        surf,
        domain=-50:50,
        domain y=-50:50,
    ] 
        {e^x*sin(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. The trigonometric functions in `pgf` assume degrees, Geogebra assume radians, so you'll need to convert, for example with `deg(x^2+y^2)`

Comment: Also, use `exp(x)*sin(x*x+y*y)` (`a^b` is implemented as `exp(b*log(a))`).